# snapshot version vs release version

Tags: git, release, snapshot, agile, scrum

we are using version as 2.2.22 and our next release should be 2.8.23.. is it a good practice to use this versioning or i just have to use it like 2.8.0 for one release and then 2.9.0 as my next release..

we are facing issues as we were unable to push the same version artifacts from release branch again if we make any bug fixes in uat.

(we only use SNAPSHOT in develop).. snapshot version will be followed by date_buildnumber.. release branch will have only the version number.

What do you think is the best approach.

Comment: How do you currently decide release numbering? How did you get from 2.2.22 to 2.8.23?

Comment: sry, its 2.8.22

Comment: Feel free to [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1):

Read

```
git help tag
```

Go to the DISCUSSION section.

Upshot: Do not ever re-tag releases.

There is a method called semantic versioning. Your version numbers look like `X.Y.Z`.

- Increment X if there is a change breaking backwards compatibility
- Increment Y for new features
- Increment Z for bugfixes